# How to understand air filter collection efficiency

Tags: automotive-engineering, material-science

It's known that air filters are used to remove particulate matter, such as vehicle cabin air filter. But I am confused whether air filter can still hold dust or particulate matter when it reaches 100% efficiency？If it is, how to explain it?

Comment: Check youtube, lots of filter tests with good explanations.

Comment: What do you mean by 100% efficiency? Traps 100% of the particles? Allows 100% flow ie no pressure drop? Both are a challenge...